# Unbound IP redirection

Tags: dns, unbound

I'm trying to redirect my LAN queries i.e. 10.0.0.0/8 to my captive portal hosted at 10.10.10.10.

I've 2 networks, 10.0.0.0/8 and 192.168.1.0/24. Objective is redirect 10.0.0.0/8 to 10.10.10.10

There's no DHCP server at the moment for this IP Pool, devices are statically mapped with 10.x.x.x/8. All DNS queries are going to Unbound resolver.

I tried creating a few changes in the unbound-config but no luck so far.

**Server:**

<Additional 3 lines below>

unblock-lan-zones: yes

insecure-lan-zones: yes

domain-insecure: "10.in-addr.arpa."

Option 1: local-zone

local-zone: "10.in-addr.arpa." transparent

forward-zone:

name: "10.in-addr.arpa."

```
        forward-addr: 10.10.10.10
```

Option 2: via define tags

define-tags: "portal"
access-control-tag: 10.0.0.0/8 "portal"

access-control-tag-action: 10.0.0.0/8 "portal" redirect

access-control-tag-data: 10.0.0.0/8 "portal" "A 10.10.10.10"

Option 3: Respip module

response-ip: 10.0.0.0/8 redirect

response-ip-data: 10.0.0.0/8 A 10.10.10.10

Can you please steer in the right direction?

Comment: What do you mean by "_LAN queries_"? All of them regardless of destination? Or just queries for off-site addresses?

Comment: Please take a look at formatting with `{}`. You can use it for blocks of configuration too

Comment: @roaima I'm trying to redirect my LAN queries i.e. 10.0.0.0/8 to my captive portal hosted at 10.10.10.10.

Comment: @roaima I've 2 networks, 10.0.0.0/8 and 192.168.1.0/24. Objective is redirect 10.0.0.0/8 to 10.10.10.10 IP

Comment: OK. Please add that to your question. To redirect DNS queries? If so, DNS queries from hosts on your LAN? Why not just fix the DNS servers given out through DHCP?

Comment: @roaima there's no DHCP server at the moment for this IP Pool, devices are statically mapped with 10.x.x.x/8. All DNS queries are going to Unbound resolver.

Comment: Please add that to your question